# React-leaflet doesn't display the map with leaflet.css loaded nor resizing

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm working on a react project using leaflet, but it doesn't display de map, here is the Map component:

```js
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import "./map.css";
    
function Map({center, zoom }) {
    return (
        <MapContainer
            className="map"
            center={center}
            zoom={zoom}
            scrollWheelZoom={false}
            style={{height:'450px'}}
        >
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
        </MapContainer>
    );
}
    
export default Map;
```

The index.html

```html
<meta
  name="description"
  content="Web site created using create-react-app"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
      crossorigin=""/>
<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;200;300;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

the css:

```css
.map {
    background-color: #424242;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Here is how it displays with no stylesheet in index.html:

[image: With no style]

And here is how it displays with the stlyesheet, which is like nothing:

[image: With stylesheet]

also here is the dependency:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.2.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-leaflet": "3.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
},
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the map container height?

Comment: Is inline, reading various examples and discussions It's better to have it there right?

Comment: In the first image, your tiles seem to be fetching correctly, but the css was off.  In the second image, your map css looks correct (proper map container and control placement), but there seems to be no tiles, as shown by the fact that your map is just an empty div with the background color you specified.  Are you sure in the second case that your map tiles are being fetched properly?

Comment: Right I missed it, sorry. Any place is fine, as long as it is already applied when Leaflet instantiates the map. Or use invalidateSize.

Comment: @SethLutske Well I'm not 100% sure that the map tiles are being fetched,  I mean, I just put the CSS from leaflet doc, I've tried both the link in index.html way and the import way, Both having the same result, how do I make sure that the map tiles are being fetched?

Comment: @ghybs already tried, but didn't work :/

Comment: Look into your dev tools network tab and see if the tiles are coming through.  Also try removing that background color and see if that makes any change for you.

Comment: At that point, it would probably be best to provide a live reproduction example, e.g.using StackBlitz or CodeSandbox.

Answer (score 3):

you should import the css form leaflet dist

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

heres is a boilerplate i made

```
/* eslint-disable */
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Map, TileLayer, LayersControl } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";


const App = () => {
  const mapRef = useRef();
  const [bounds, setbounds] = useState([
    [-90, -180],
    [90, 180],
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <Map
        ref={mapRef}
        center={[0, 0]}
        zoom={3}
        maxZoom={19}
        minZoom={2}
        bounceAtZoomLimits={true}
        maxBoundsViscosity={0.95}
        maxBounds={bounds}
      >
        <LayersControl position="topright">
          <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="OpenStreet">
            <TileLayer
              noWrap={false}
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
          </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
          <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="Satellite">
            <TileLayer
              noWrap={false}
              url="https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png"
            />
          </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
          <LayersControl.BaseLayer checked name="Dark">
            <TileLayer
              noWrap={false}
              url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
            />
          </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
        </LayersControl>
      </Map>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

aswell dont fortget to create a css with this class

```
.leaflet-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

also keep in mind im using

```
"react-leaflet": "^2.7.0",
"leaflet": "^1.7.1"
```

verisons

Answer (score 0):

include css in head index.html  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>`